# Given a pair of currencies, are there one or several interbank currency exchange rates?

Tags: foreign-exchange, currency, terminology

Let's consider a pair of currencies, e.g. EUR -> USD. Are there one or several interbank currency exchange rates?

I see that both Revolut and [OFX](https://www.ofx.com/en-us/exchange-rates/) claim to use the interbank currency exchange rate, but when I look at their exchange rate, they differ slightly (e.g., currently, 1 EUR = 1.0935 USD on Revolut vs. 1 EUR [=](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QAG9w.png) 1.0949 USD on OFX). I don't know whether this is due to quote lag or different interbank currency exchange rates.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Historic Forex Rates - why are they different and what's the source of truth](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/149460/historic-forex-rates-why-are-they-different-and-whats-the-source-of-truth)

Comment: Per linked answer to similar question - there is no singular datafeed / 'source of the truth', small timing diffs can have an impact, and methodologies used by the data provider could also differ [see discussion there on some reasons why].

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon thanks, no, in this question, I focus on the interbank currency exchange rate(s?) only: given a pair of currencies, are there one or several interbank currency exchange rates? I.e., I wonder whether the interbank currency exchange rate is a unique rate.

Comment: And what exactly is 'The Interbank Currency Exchange Rate'? There is no mandated rate that banks will exchange with eachother [unless you are referring to a country with a controlled currency, in which case you can pull the government rate, unless you are referring to grey-market rates... etc. etc.]. I expect that such a reference would be contrasting with a 'retail rate' that you would get if you walked into a bank (probably 1-2% worse than what you see on a data feed).

Comment: I see now in the linked similar questions that you asked the same thing a couple of days ago, and got a great answer with discussion on this. Not sure what you're actually looking for at this point.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon thanks, got it, you're welcome to post it as an answer. This current question is focusing on what the "Interbank Currency Exchange Rate" refers to.

Comment: I retracted my close vote as your last question on this is the better link, with a more comprehensive answer. I can't link that one as I've already attempted to close as duplicate, but no value in what I've written in these comments that isn't already there.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon AKdemy's answer mentions "FX trading is decentralized and takes place through transactions at brokerages, over-the-counter (OTC) markets, or via the interbank system", but it doesn't answer the question "Given a pair of currencies, are there one or several interbank currency exchange rates?".

Comment: I would imagine there could be as many interbank exchange rates as there are pairs of banks trading in the currency. What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: @littleadv I'm looking for the answer the question "Given a pair of currencies, are there one or several interbank currency exchange rates". Your comment answered there are several interbank currency exchange rates. You're welcome to post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's  no reason to think there's a central universal authority managing exchange rates between all the banks in the world. While some conspiracy theorists claim there's such an authority, I've seen no evidence of its existence. As your own empirical evidence suggests, there's more than one "interbank exchange rate", and my logic would suggest that there could be as many such rates as there are pairs of banks in the world trading in the currency.

The reason "interbank rate" is used for reference is because of large volume of trading between banks, compared to retail traders. As such, interbank rates are less susceptible to manipulation or influence.